# Dropped connections to server. Haproxy + Nginx + Unicorn

Tags: nginx, unicorn, haproxy, cloud66

Some requests to my site are failed with "Server unexpectedly dropped the connection" and there is no errors in error logs.

RPM is 1-1.2k.

Do you have any ideas?

Here is configs of haproxy, nginx and unicorn:

https://gist.github.com/releu/59b7f1d649c681856320

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you share logs which is critical you have misconfiguration:

1. Nginx worker_connections      3000
   Reason: keep it 2-3x more than actual active connections number
2. Nginx worker_rlimit_nofile    20000.
   Reason: each single connection requires 2 file descriptors for serving request via proxying
3. Nginx absence of location that serves static files straight from file system bypass backend.
   Reason: if you pass any static file via backend it reach the limit very quick
4. Unicorn worker_processes 4.
   Reason: 4 workers are not enough to serve 1K RPM
5. System: I guess there is lack of kernel optimisation.
   Take a look [Unicorn System Kernel tips](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/TUNING.html)

Comment: Looks like the main problem was in worker_connections.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be an issue with your Unicorn config - it's set to have a backlog of 1024, which could cause some issues despite being the default setting.

From the [Unicorn documentation](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html): "If you are running unicorn on multiple machines, lowering this number can help your load balancer detect when a machine is overloaded and give requests to a different machine."

It may also be worth monitoring your system resources when this happens. Please let us know how this goes for you!

Comment: May be, but there is no errors in unicorn's log files and ha-proxy had not captured any bad responses.